# Slicing a dataframe from unstack()

Tags: pandas

This is a dataframe, df that emerged using a unstack()

```
Index       0         7       21      22      23   
June       89        0        3       5        2
July       30          0        2       5        4
August   20        8        5       5        5
```

I tried to slice a portion of the dataframe using

```
df2=df.loc[: , :'21']
```

I tried to slice a portion of the dataframe using

```
df2=df.loc[: , :'21']
```

But I have this error:

> keyError: '21'

Comment: It may be is a number, did you try  just `21`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error mean there is no column `21` as string.

Check it by:

```
#integers columns
print (df.columns.tolist())
[0, 7, 21, 22, 23]

#strings columns
#print (df.columns.tolist())
#['0', '7', '21', '22', '23']
```

You can use for `Series` integer `21`:

```
df2 = df[21]
print (df2)
Index
June      3
July      2
August    5
Name: 21, dtype: int64
```

And for one columns `DataFrame` use double `[]`:

```
df2 = df[[21]]
print (df2)
        21
Index     
June     3
July     2
August   5
```

EDIT:

Another problem should be trailing whitespaces:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['0', '7', '  21    ', '22', '23']
```

and for remove need [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

print (df.columns.tolist())
['0', '7', '21', '22', '23']
```

EDIT1:

For filter columns with values less as `24` with bad data also use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for `NaN`s for unparseable values:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, pd.to_numeric(df.columns, errors='coerce') < 24]
```

Comment: its a dataframe with column headers ranging from 0 to 23. But what I really want to do is plot all the rows against columns 0 to 21 excluding coulmn 22 and 23

Comment: Ok, so there is missing a lot of columns, do you want add them? What is default value for added columns? `0`? `NaN` ?

Comment: no, there are no missing columns. Just the columns:0,7,21,22,23

Comment: OK, and your columns was integers or was necessary used `str.strip` ?

Comment: OK, then use `df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns < 24]`

Comment: i got this:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Hmmm, so there are no `integers`, is possible use `df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.astype(int) < 24]` ?

Comment: It has a last column named : 'Multiple'  so it showed this ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Multiple'

Comment: Ok, then need `df2 = df.loc[:, pd.to_numeric(df.columns, errors='coerce') < 24]`.

Comment: Wow!! Your communication is excellent and your comments have been extremely helpful. It worked a great deal,thanks. please edit so I can click the check sign